# Sending Arrays from View to Controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to send the following values from view to controller

```
        var ParamAliasArray = new Object();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

            ParamAliasArray[i] = $("#txtParamAlias" + i).val();
        }
        var ParamValueArray = new Object();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            ParamValueArray[i] = new Array();
            for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {

                ParamValueArray[i][j] = $("#txtParamValue" + i).val();
            }
        }
```

one is 1D array and other is 2D array I am passing as

```
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true

        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'Register/GetRegDataFromuser',
            data: JSON.stringify({ GloabalAppID: GlobalAppID,
                    TransactionID: TransactionID,
                    OwnerID: OwnerID,
                    ParamAliasArray: ParamAliasArray,
                   ParamValueArray: ParamValueArray }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.debug(data);
            }
        });
```

I have written Action method as in

```
public ActionResult GetRegDataFromuser(int GloabalAppID, int TransactionID, string OwnerID, string[] ParamAliasArray, string[][] ParamValueArray)
{

---some logic--

}
```

So,I am not able to pass the array to the action method from View..Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `ParamValueArray[i][j]=new Array();` this line.